# Nested Properties and FirstOrDefault

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, razor-pages

I tried to get the first element inside a nested query using FirstOrDefault, but I alaways have a problem. I tried to debug and I can see that no element is returning in fact and I don't understand why.

Here is what I've done so far.

In the Index.cshtml page.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="table-dark">
                
                <a asp-page="./Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@Model.FromSort">
                    <dt>
                        @Html.DisplayName("From")
                    </dt>
                    <dd>  @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Trip[0].TripStations.First().Station.Name)</dd>
                </a>
            </th>
            <th class="table-dark">

                <a asp-page="./Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@Model.ToSort">
                    <dt>
                        @Html.DisplayName("To")
                    </dt>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Trip[0].TripStations.Last().Station.Name)
                </a>
            </th>

...

<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model.TripD.Trips) {
            string selectedRow = "";
            if (item.ID == Model.TripID)
            {
                selectedRow = "table-success";
            }
            <tr class="@selectedRow">
            <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TripStations.FirstOrDefault().Station.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TripStations.LastOrDefault().Station.Name)
            </td>
```

From Index.cshtml.cs

```
if (id != null)
            {
                TripID = id.Value;
                Trip trip = TripD.Trips
                .Where(i => i.ID == id.Value).Single();
                TripD.Categories =trip.TripCategories.Select(s => s.Category);
                trip = TripD.Trips.Where(Trips => Trips.ID == id.Value).Single();
                TripD.TripStations = (IEnumerable<TripStation>) trip.TripStations.Select(s => s.Station);
            }
```

In the models I have the following.

```
Trip Model:

public ICollection<TripStation>? TripStations { get; set; }

TripStation Model:

public class TripStation
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int TripID { get; set; }
        public Trip Trip { get; set; }
        public int StationID { get; set; }
        public Station Station { get; set; }
    }

Station Model:

public ICollection<TripStation>? TripStations { get; set; }
```

And here is what I added "From" and "To" to the list of stations.

```
public class TripStationUtilities
    {

        public ICollection<TripStation> MoveStations(ICollection<TripStation> l)
        {
            var ToStation = l.Skip(1).First();
            l.Remove(ToStation);
            l.Add(ToStation);

            return l;
        }

    }
```

For now, nothing is returned.

I've tried before to create two properties of type Station for "From" and "To", but I thought is not neccessary if I already has the many-to-many connection between Trip and Station and I tried to use that.

What I've tried to return was the property Name from the first and last Stations specific for any Trip.

Comment: You just need the first and last items.  If you get count and the number is 5 than just delete the three items in the middle : int count = l.Count(); l.skip(1).Remove(count - 2);

Comment: Can you provide a minimal executable demo？